# How was Crime and Punishment originally published?

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, textual-history, crime-and-punishment

I know that *Crime and Punishment* was originally published in "The Russian Messenger". I read that it was a Monthly journal. But how exactly was *Crime and Punishment* formatted in its initial release? Was one Chapter released per month with each publication of the Russian Messenger? Or did they release Part One in one journal release? I also don't really know how The Russian Messenger was formatted in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was published during 1866 in the issues 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12. Dostoyevsky was still writing the novel in 1866 during the publication and finished it only in November or December.

January issue with part one (number III):

[image: January 1866]

February issue with part two (it says "Part 1, chapters VIII-XIII") (number II):

[image: February 1866]

April issue with part three (it says "Part 2, chapters I-VI")  (number VI)

[image: April 1866]

June issue with part four, chapters I-IV (it says "Part 2, chapters VII-IX")  (number VIII)

[image: June 1866]

July issue with part four, chapters V-VI, part five, chapters I-III (it says "Part 2, chapters X-XIII")  (number XI)

[image: July 1866]

August issue with part five, chapters IV-V (it says "Part 2, chapters XIV-XV") (number VIII)

[image: August 1866]

November issue with part six, chapters I-VI (it says "Part 3, chapters I-VI") (number II):

[image: November 1866]

December issue with part six chapters VII-VIII and epilogue (it says "The ending") (number IV):

[image: December 1866]

Comment: Wow cool. So how many chapters were published at once? there are 6 part but 8 magazine releases right? What I am most interested in is whether or nor par1 chapter 6 and part1 chapter 7 where published simultaneously?

Comment: @ChrisFraser I added the whole publication shchedule

Comment: Could you add a translation of (the relevant parts of) the text shown in the images? For those who don't understand Russian, the answer to the question isn't really clear from the images alone.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The only relevant part here is the original parts and chapters numeration. And I've already translated it.